# Deserializing json with explicit null tags in the request not identified as null in java class constructor

Tags: java, rest, jackson-databind

I came across a strange problem today with Deserializing json with explicit null tags.

Below is the sample request and java code.

```
{
 "name": "Jhon"
 "address": "Earth"
 "department" : [{
    "depName": null,
    "depId" : "1234"
}]
}
```

---

```
public class Department {

private String depName;
private String depId;

public Department(){
       if(this.depName == null){
          this.depName = "general";
       }
    }
}
```

If I remove the depName from the request the constructor gets called and depName is set as

> "general"

If I keep it in the request, the constructor is called but depName is not set.

Why do I see this behavior and what is the solution to this.

Comment: ok so when u delete depName it becomes null and as per ur condition if depName == null then set depName as general ...and after it is set to general the condition is false as it is not null hence it doesnt change

Comment: If you debug the code in your constructor, what value does `this.depName` have when `"depName": null` ? Maybe it is being set to `"null"` as a `String`